# MediaStreamSource in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, audio

I need to play a custom audio stream in WPF. I can deal with the mp3/wmv restrictions.

The MediaStreamSource class seems ideal, but all the examples I have seen are Silverlight 3.

Is there a WPF equivalent?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) to play custom audio streams in WPF. It can make use of any ACM codecs installed, or you can write your own in managed code.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, this is actually what I did in the end. I use their WaveStream and WaveOut classes to play the audio but I put a custom stream implementation in the chain to to all the needed manipulation before output.

Cheers

Pete

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of MediaStreamSource in WPF.

When you say you want to play a custom audio stream, what do you mean?  Do you need to add post processing on the audio?  Is it a custom file-type?

Can MediaElement/MediaPlayer WPF classes do the job?